# Cannot load dynamically a project in VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

As I work on an application with many projects in the same solution (VS2019), to keep resources, I often unload or load different projects, depending on the one I am working on.
That's why I want to create a plug-in that will allow to save a certain configuration of projects loaded and unloaded.
By now, I can easily unload a project in my current DTE, for example :

```
IVsSolution solution = (IVsSolution)sp.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));
IVsSolution4 solution4 = (IVsSolution4)sp.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));

// Close all projects
foreach (Project project in projectsFromDTE)
{
    IVsHierarchy hierarchy;
    solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(project.UniqueName, out hierarchy);
    Guid guidProjectID;
    solution.GetGuidOfProject(hierarchy, out guidProjectID);
    solution4.UnloadProject(guidProjectID, (uint)_VSProjectUnloadStatus.UNLOADSTATUS_UnloadedByUser);
}
```

But I cannot figure how to LOAD these projects. I have found this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/managing-project-loading-in-a-solution?view=vs-2019 
Any idea how I can use it?

NB: sorry for the typos or grammatical errors, english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: IVsSolution4.ReloadSolution not work for you?

Comment: Thank you. I finally managed to do it, by using this : 
                        solution4.ReloadProject(guidProjectID);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it, by using this :

```
IVsHierarchy hierarchy;
                    solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(projectFileName, out hierarchy);
                    Guid guidProjectID;
                    solution.GetGuidOfProject(hierarchy, out guidProjectID);
                    solution4.ReloadProject(guidProjectID);
```

where projectFileName is the path to the .csproj.